# Do not use JSDoc (/** … */) for implementation comments?

Tags: comments, jsdoc

I was going through https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#formatting-comments to understand the style guide Google is setting for their developers.

Google accepts the following styles:

```
 /*
  * This is
  * okay.
 */

// And so
// is this.

/* This is fine, too. */
```

But interestingly, Google mentions `Do not use JSDoc (/** … */) for implementation comments.`

I have been using JSDOC styling for my past projects.

Any idea why is it not recommended?

Answer (score 2):

The Google Style Guide [Terminology Notes](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#terminology-notes)

> The term comment always refers to implementation comments. We do not
> use the phrase documentation comments, instead using the common term
> “JSDoc” for both human-readable text and machine-readable annotations
> within /** … */.

```js
/**
 * Use JSDoc for documentation comments
 * @param {type} param description
 */
function someFunction(param) {
  // Do not use JSDoc for implementation comments
  const alias = goog.require('my.long.name.alias');
  // ...
}

  [1]: https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#terminology-notes
```